# Find items who content have 404 links

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm running a script in which I'm trying to get the item whose content has broken links, (links that redirect the user to a page with 404 as response). But I always get the same result, no broken links. However, I still have to identify a couple of items that should appear on the final report.

Does anyone know how I can get those items on a report?

Here is the script:

```
$database = "master"
$root = Get-Item -Path (@{$true="$($database):"; $false="$($database):\content\"}[(Test-Path -Path "$($database):\content\")]) 
$linksToCheck =  @("internal")
$linkTypes = [ordered]@{"Internal Links"="internal";"External Links (General Link only)"="external"};

$versionOptions = [ordered]@{
    "Latest"="1"
}

$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="root"; Title="Choose the report root"; Tooltip="Only items in this branch will be returned."; Columns=9},
        @{Name="searchVersion"; Value="1"; Title="Version"; Options=$versionOptions; Tooltip="Choose a version."; Columns="3"; Placeholder="All"},
        @{Name="linksToCheck"; Title="Link types to check"; Options=$linkTypes; Tooltip="which link types you want to check"; Editor="checklist"} 
    )
    Title = "Broken Links Report"
    Description = "Choose the criteria for the report."
    Width = 550
    Height = 300
    ShowHints = $true
    Icon = [regex]::Replace($PSScript.Appearance.Icon, "Office", "OfficeWhite", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
}

$result = Read-Variable @props

if($result -eq "cancel"){
    exit
}

filter HasBrokenLink {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$Item,

        [Parameter()]
        [bool]$IncludeAllVersions
    )

    if(!$Item) { return }
    if($linksToCheck.Contains("internal")) {
        $brokenLinks = $item.Links.GetBrokenLinks($IncludeAllVersions)
        if($brokenlinks -ne $null -and $brokenlinks.Length -gt 0) {
            $finalRenderings = Get-Rendering -Item $Item -FinalLayout
            $sharedRenderings = Get-Rendering -Item $Item
            $uniqueIdLookup = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]
            foreach($brokenLink in $brokenLinks) {
                if([ID]::IsNullOrEmpty($brokenLink.SourceFieldID)) { continue }
                $fieldItem = Get-Item -Path "$($Item.Database.Name):\" -ID $brokenLink.SourceFieldID
                if(!$fieldItem) { continue }
                $renderings = & {
                    switch($fieldItem.ID) {
                        "{04BF00DB-F5FB-41F7-8AB7-22408372A981}" {
                            $finalRenderings
                        }
                        default {
                            $sharedRenderings
                        }
                    }
                }
                $brokenRendering = $renderings | Where-Object { $_.Datasource -eq $brokenLink.TargetPath -and !$uniqueIdLookup.Contains($_.UniqueId) } | Select-Object -First 1
                if(!$brokenRendering) { continue }
                $uniqueIdLookup.Add($brokenRendering.UniqueId) > $null
                $brokenRenderingItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $brokenRendering.ItemId
                $brokenItem = [pscustomobject]@{
                    "ID"=$Item.ID
                    "Icon"=$Item.__Icon
                    "DisplayName"=$Item.DisplayName
                    "ItemPath"=$Item.ItemPath
                    "Version"=$Item.Version
                    "Language"=$Item.Language
                    "__Updated"=$Item.__Updated
                    "__Updated by"=$Item."__Updated by"
                    "Link Field"=$fieldItem.Name
                    "Rendering" = $brokenRenderingItem.Name
                    "Target Path"=$brokenLink.TargetPath
                    "Status Code"="Missing Target Item"
                    "BrokenLink"=$brokenLink
                    "Link Type" = "Internal"
                }

                $brokenItem

            }
        }
    }

    if($linksToCheck.Contains("external")){
        if($IncludeAllVersions){
            $allItems = Get-Item "$($item.Database.Name):" -Version * -Language * -Id $item.Id
        } else {
            $allItems = @(Get-Item "$($item.Database.Name):" -Language * -Id $item.Id)
        }
        foreach($checkedItem in $allItems){
            foreach($field in $checkedItem.Fields) {
                if ($field.Type -eq 'General Link' -and $field.Value -like '*linktype="external"*') { 
                    $found = $field.Value -match '.*url="(.*?)".*'
                    if($found) {
                        $url = $matches[1]
                    }

                    try{ 
                        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing -Method head
                    } 
                    catch {
                        $statuscode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__

                        if(!$statuscode) {
                            $statuscode = "Not reachable"
                        }

                        $brokenItem = [pscustomobject]@{
                            "ID"=$checkedItem.ID
                            "Icon"=$checkedItem.__Icon
                            "DisplayName"=$checkedItem.DisplayName
                            "ItemPath"=$checkedItem.ItemPath
                            "Version"=$checkedItem.Version
                            "Language"=$checkedItem.Language
                            "__Updated"=$checkedItem.__Updated
                            "__Updated by"=$checkedItem."__Updated by"
                            "Link Field"=$field.Name
                            "Target Path"=$url
                            "Status Code"=$statuscode
                            "Link Type"="External"
                        }

                        $brokenItem
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$items = @($root) + @(($root.Axes.GetDescendants() | Initialize-Item)) | HasBrokenLink -IncludeAllVersions (!$searchVersion)

if($items.Count -eq 0){
    Show-Alert "There are no items found which have broken links in the current language."
} else {
    $props = @{
        Title = "Broken Links Report"
        InfoTitle = "$($items.Count) items with broken links found!"
        InfoDescription = "The report checked for $($linksToCheck -join ' & ') links in $(@('all versions','latest versions')[[byte]($searchVersion='1')]) of items."
        MissingDataMessage = "There are no items found which have broken links in the current language."
        PageSize = 25
        ViewName = "BrokenLinks"
        Property = @(
            "Icon","Status Code", 
            @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName} }, 
            @{Label="Item Path"; Expression={$_.ItemPath} },"Link Field", "Rendering","Target Path",
            "Link Type",
            "Version",
            "Language",
            @{Label="Updated"; Expression={$_.__Updated} },
            @{Label="Updated by"; Expression={$_."__Updated by"} }
        )
    }

    $items | Show-ListView @props
}
Close-Window
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following PS snippet to fetch all the broken links from the database:

```
function GetBrokenLinks {
param([string]$db)

  $database= [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetDatabase($db)
  $linkDb = [Sitecore.Globals]::LinkDatabase
  $itemLinks = $linkDb.GetBrokenLinks($database)
  $brokenItems = @()
  foreach($itemlink in $itemLinks){
    $sourceItem = Get-Item -Path $db -ID $itemLink.SourceItemID
    if($sourceItem.Paths.IsContentItem -or $sourceItem.Paths.IsMediaItem){
       $sourceField = $sourceItem.Fields[$itemlink.SourceFieldID]
       $brokenItem = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
       $brokenItem | Add-Member -Name 'ID' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $sourceItem.ID
       $brokenItem | Add-Member -Name 'Path' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $sourceItem.Paths.FullPath
       $brokenItem | Add-Member -Name 'Field' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $sourceField.DisplayName
       $brokenItem | Add-Member -Name 'FieldType' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $sourceField.Type
       $brokenItem | Add-Member -Name 'BrokenID' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $itemlink.TargetPath
       $brokenItems +=  $brokenItem 
    }
  }
  $brokenItems | Show-ListView  -Property `
    @{ Label = "Item ID"; Expression = { $_.ID } },
    @{ Label = "Item Path"; Expression = { $_.Paths.FullPath } },
    @{ Label = "Field"; Expression = { $_.Field } },
    @{ Label = "Field Type"; Expression = { $_.FieldType } },
    @{ Label = "Broken ID"; Expression = { $_.BrokenID } }
 }

 GetBrokenLinks "master"
```

Above function takes database name as a parameter and returns the output in tabular format which can be easily downloaded.

[image]

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script to get broken links using powershell script -

```
# Set the root item from which you want to start checking for broken links
$rootItem = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/YourRootItem"

# Define a function to check if a link is broken
function Check-BrokenLink {
    param (
        [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField
    )

    if ($linkField -ne $null) {
        $targetItem = $linkField.TargetItem
        if ($targetItem -eq $null) {
            Write-Output "Broken link found: $($linkField.Item.Paths.FullPath) - $($linkField.Value)"
        }
    }
}

# Recursive function to check all items under the specified root item
function Check-AllItems {
    param (
        [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$item
    )

    # Check if the item is null
    if ($item -eq $null) {
        return
    }

    # Check for broken links in the item
    $item.Fields | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -is [Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]) {
            Check-BrokenLink -linkField $_
        }
    }

    # Recursively check all child items
    $item.Children | ForEach-Object {
        Check-AllItems -item $_
    }
}

# Start checking for broken links from the root item
Check-AllItems -item $rootItem
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Sitecore instance, you can get the broken link report by the following steps.

1. In your start menu, go to `Reporting Tools` => `PowerShell Reports` => `Content Audit` => `Broken Links`

[image]

2. Provide the report root, check link types and version.

[image]

It will generate a report for you.

Hope this helps.